# Insert in empty column of table obtaining values from a join

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift, sql-insert

I have these two tables:

rbi_world_holi_prov

```
accentcity      region_name
Madrid          Madrid
Barcelona       Cataluña
Berlin          Berlin
Sevilla         Andalucia
```

rbi_ip

```
ip                city      region_name
85.59.64.116      Berlin    <null>
195.235.205.150   Madrid    <null>
83.231.53.43      Barcelona <null>
2.136.208.188     Sevilla   <null>
```

I want to get this:

```
ip                city      region_name
85.59.64.116      Berlin    Berlin
195.235.205.150   Madrid    Madrid
83.231.53.43      Barcelona Cataluña
2.136.208.188     Sevilla   Andalucia
```

With the following query, I get what I want to:

```
select i.city,i.ip,w.region_name 
from rbi_ip as i
inner join rbi_world_holi_prov as w
on lower(i.city) =lower(w.accentcity)
```

However, if I add this insert statement:

```
insert into rbi_ip (region_name)
select i.city,i.ip,w.region_name 
from rbi_ip as i
inner join rbi_world_holi_prov as w
on lower(i.city) =lower(w.accentcity)
```

I get this:

```
ip                city      region_name
85.59.64.116      Berlin    <null>
195.235.205.150   Madrid    <null>
83.231.53.43      Barcelona <null>
2.136.208.188     Sevilla   <null>
<null>            <null>    Madrid
<null>            <null>    Cataluña
<null>            <null>    Berlin
<null>            <null>    Sevilla
```

I also have tried with a left join, getting the same result. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont want to insert in the table you want to update column.

```
update rbi_ip
set rbi_ip.region_name = rbi_world_holi_prov.region_name 
from rbi_world_holi_prov
where lower(rbi_ip.city) = lower(rbi_world_holi_prov .accentcity)
```

Comment: Just edit the statement, replacing 't2.' in second line of the code with 'w.' (as 'w' is later used as table 2 synonym)

Comment: With that query I get the next error:
Invalid operation: relation "rbi" does not exist.
I have tried to explicitely name the table using update rbi_ip but then I get: Invalid operation: column "rbi" of relation "rbi_ip_backup" does not exist

Comment: @dimo raichev haha I pressed enter without intention, it is already edited

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás can you try it again, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
you can also use alias name for the table while updating data , just like i have used i here 

Update i Set region_name =w.region_name
from rbi_ip_backup as i
inner join rbi_world_holi_prov as w
on lower(i.city) =lower(w.accentcity)
```

Then use

```
Select * from rbi_ip_backup
```